# Set List row Background based on position in Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have a a custom Adapter that is used to build a List. In my adapter I want the First,second and third row to show specific colours as their individual Backgrounds,To achieve this am using the below Code. However it seems that the backgrounds are being copied even to rows that are not  (0,1,2). I seems the row immediately below the bottom row will be treated as row (0) and so on and get the backgounds. How would I solve this:

```
public class TopfragmentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

 public TopfragmentAdapter (Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

}


public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public static class ViewHolder {
   TextView name;
   TextView track;
   TextView number;
   ImageView thumb;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bnmtoptenlistrow, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.topten_artist_name); 
    holder.track = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.topten_album_name); 
    holder.number= (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.topten_number);
    holder.thumb=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.topten_list_image); 

    vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hash = data.get(position);



    holder.name.setText("Artist: "+hash.get(TopListfragment.KEY_NAME));
    holder.track.setText("Track: "+hash.get(TopListfragment.KEY_TRACK_NAME));
    holder.number.setText(hash.get(TopListfragment.KEY_NUMBER)+" listens");
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(hash.get(TopListfragment.KEY_IMAGE_URL), holder.thumb);

    SetRowColour(vi,position);
    return vi;
}

private void SetRowColour(View view,int Position){
    if( Position==0){

        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gold_gradient);
   }
    else if( Position==1){
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.silver_gradient);
   }
    else if( Position==2){
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bronze_gradient);
   }
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I had to assign a position to the underlying data and use that to alternate colors. (The position in the view is just the relative position of the object, which, as I found out, is a bit variable depending on things like how fast you scroll the view.)

I created my own object and used an ArrayList of that object and as I was initializing my object assigned a position (basically the offset). Then I did modulo math on my object position.

```
TransList tl = entries.get(position);   // TransList is my own object, entries is the array list of objects
int Position = tl.getPosition();

if ( (Position % 3) == 0 ) {
} else if ( (Position % 3) == 1 ) {
} else if ( (Position % 3) == 2 ) {
}
```